# Редиректы в modrewrite

Tags: apache

У меня есть сайт в котором лежит две html страницы и .htaccess

> volk@Sivadra:~$ ls -a ~/web/test.dev/
> .  ..  .directory  .htaccess  page1.html  page2.html

.htaccess выглядеть вот так

> volk@Sivadra:~$ cat ~/web/test.dev/.htaccess 
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule page1.html page2.html

Но когда я захожу на test.dev/page1.html редиректа **не происходит**. Команда показывающая модули апачя показывает что модуль rewrite есть

> volk@Sivadra:~$ apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep -i "rewrite"
>  rewrite_module (shared)

Даже если просмотреть директорию с модулями показано опубликованная ссылка есть

> volk@Sivadra:~$ ls -Fal /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/  | grep -i "rewrite"
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 июля  30 14:06 rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load

Содержание файла на которого ссылается эта ссылка

> volk@Sivadra:~$ cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load 
> LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

Даже на всякий случай проверил существует ли этот модуль

> volk@Sivadra:~$ file /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=69db4255e339924d7facba51f8429824109cd398, stripped

Файл виртуального хоста выглядит вот так:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.dev
    ServerAlias www.test.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/volk/web/test.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        <Directory "/home/volk/web/test.dev">
            Require all granted
            Options +Indexes
        </Directory> </VirtualHost>
```

Почему не происходить редирект?

Answer (score 1):

1. Потому что вы не указали RewriteCond
2. Потому что rewrite это не редирект.

Редирект это вот - Redirect 301 page1.html page2.html

Comment: А не могли бы вы подсказать как в таком случае должен выглядеть .htaccess, а то у меня как то не получается самостоятельно его составить.

Comment: Читай выше  Redirect 301 page1.html page2.html это все